# Distributing multiplication of rational functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, rational-functions

I am having trouble distributing with fractions. This

$$ \left(\frac{1}{(x + 3)} + \frac{(x + 3)}{(x - 3)}\right)\, (9 - x^2) = -\frac{(x^2-3)}{9-x^2}(9-x^2) $$

has the answer $\left\{\left[x = - \frac{9}{7}\right]\right\}$.

I start solving by cancelling $(9-x^2)$ on the right hand side, and multiplying $(9-x^2)$ with the terms on the left hand side by foiling (multiplying term by term). So the first step is

$$9\times\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{9 (x+3)}{x-3}-x^2\times\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{x^2 (x+3) }{x-3}=-x^2-3$$

This is apparently wrong because it has another answer, $\left\{\left[x = - \frac{3}{7}\right]\right\}$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the RHS, you want $-(x^2 - 3) = -x^2 + 3$. Also, I wouldn't FOIL: Just distribute $9 - x^2 $ to both fractions, you'll get cancellation that way. Your way works, you're just doing extra work only to undo it.

Comment: You can cancel $9-x^2$ in that way IF $9-x^2\ne0$.  If $9-x^2=0$ then $x=\pm3$.  So $3$ and $-3$ are solutions, and whatever other solutions there may be would be solutions of the equation you're left with after you do that cancellation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks pjs36, this is right on track. I forgot putting in parenthesis in $-(x^2-3)$ in the RHS when canceling $9-x^2$. Now it generates the correct result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancelling $(9-x^2)$ on the RHS leaves you with $-(x^2-3)$. Next I'd recommend finding a common denominator and combining the fractions inside the parentheses on the LHS. You should get $$ \frac{1}{\left(x + 3\right)} + \frac{\left(x + 3\right)}{\left(x - 3\right)} =  \frac{x-3+(x+3)^2}{x^2 - 9}$$ which means the LHS will simplify to $-(x-3+(x+3)^2)$, leaving you with $$-(x-3+(x+3)^2) = -(x^2-3)$$ Can you take it from here? If I carry out the rest of this algebra I find that $x = \frac{-9}{7}$.

Comment: I forgot putting in parenthesis in $-(x^2-3)$ when canceling $(9-x^2)$ from the RHS! That's tricky! They are not there to begin with. I guess I'm not used to putting them in as much as taking them away... I'll figure out the rest, I know some ways are better than others, I was just hoping to solve this one way or another, now I have faith in math again!

Comment: Negatives can be tricky to keep track of. Unfortunately they sometimes make all the difference. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\frac{1}{x+3} + \frac{x+3}{x-3} \right) ( 9 -x^2) -x^2 -3$

It will be

$\frac{9-x^2}{x+3} + \frac{(x+3)(9-x^2)}{x-3} = -x^2 - 3 $

after that

$\frac{(9-x^2)(x-3)}{(x+3)(x-3)} + \frac{(x+3)(x+3)(9-x^2)}{(x-3)(x+3)} = -x^2 -3 $

Note that $9-x^2 = -(x^2 - 9) = -(x+3)(x-3)$, i.e., you can cancel it with the denominator